# Error con bootstrap-table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap

trato de darle el estilo de Bootstrap-table a una tabla, pero me marca el siguiente error y no se por que, si en otras tablas si funciona:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'field' of undefined
    at HTMLTableCellElement.<anonymous>
```

//agregar BootstrapTable

```
$("#datosTable").bootstrapTable({
       pagination: true,
       showFooter: true,
       search: true,
       showExport:true,
       filter: true,
       method: 'post',
       showRefresh:true,
       pageList:[10, 25, 50, 100, 'All'],
       showPaginationSwitch: true
});
```

"Los datos de la tabla ya están cargados, solo es darle estilo, paginado y las propiedades que me muestran"

> Este es el `HTML` de mi tabla "obvio tiene mas datos esto es solo para
>   una idea"

```
<table id="datosTable" class="table table-striper table-bordered table-hover">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <td colspan="2">Lugar</td>
         <td colspan="2">CHIN</td>
         <td colspan="2">EUA</td>
         <td colspan="2">MEX</td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
         <td>Nombre</td>
         <td>Nº</td>
         <td>Peso.</td>
         <td>%</td>
         <td>Peso.</td>
         <td>%</td><td>Peso.</td>
         <td>%</td>

      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Acero </td>
         <td>43a</td>
         <td>0.47</td>
         <td>6800</td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td>0</td>
         <td>0</td>

      </tr>
      </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: fijate si estas añadiendo las librerias correctamente, parece ser que no estas incluyendo el jquery

Comment: @LuisFernando si la incluye ya que creo otras tablas y si lo agrega.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me leí una parte de la documentación sobre Bootstrap Table [aquí.](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/getting-started/)

Supongo que el error recae sobre los elementos `TD` que tienes sobre el `THEAD`. En la documentación se muestra (y de hecho en todos los ejemplos que hay) que todas las celdas que estén dentro de `THEAD` deben de ir con la etiqueta `TH`.

Entonces, intenta cambiar tus etiquetas `TD` dentro de tu `THEAD` por etiquetas `TH`.

Comment: si era eso, muchas gracias.